# C# API works in Postman, but not in a Xamarin API call

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, api, xamarin

I'm trying to call an API like this:

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
{
    try
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    
        var url = "https://my_ipv4:my_port/" + "api/" + "Usuarios";

        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsuarioViewModel>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
        else
        {
            var theError = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var x = default(UsuarioViewModel);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

I get this response:

> { StatusCode: 400,
> ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request',
> Version: 1.1,
> Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
> {
> Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
> Date: Sun, 04 Sep 2022 23:52:37 GMT
> Connection: close
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
> Content-Length: 334
> }}

The API seems to work in Postman using `https://localhost:my_port/api/Usuarios` and I've already called some public APIs and they worked, so the problems seems to be the way of setting my Url.

var theError returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 
4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us- 
ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: what is the reason for bad request? are you missing any headers since you clear them all, or need to add any headers in for the api such as a subscription key or auth key?

Comment: postman can generate c# that you can then paste into your code

Comment: Looks like the server returns `Content-Type: text/html` with `Content-Length: 334` of content (of HTML). You are expecting JSON so ether you are hitting wrong URL or there is some other problem which those `Content-Length: 334` bytes of server response which you've omitted might have some clues for

Comment: in your `else` statement, add `var theError = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` then paste that string in your question.

Comment: I added var theError to the post. Invalid Hostname seems to be the answer but I dont know what hostname to pick, ipv4 doesnt work nor does localhost

Comment: you aren't literally using `my_port` as your port, are you?

Comment: ive tried using the ports that IIS Express shows me under the Browse Applications menu

Comment: Stitching of the variable `url` : Is `my_ipv4:my_port` of the `"https://my_ipv4:my_port/" + "api/" + "Usuarios"` stitching error?